# Lan/Ethernet card for ASUS P8Z68-V PRO/GEN3 for gaming with LOW ping/delay for under $40

Tags: gaming, ethernet

**I need a card for less than $40, not more, good for gaming with low ping/delay/latency.**

My current LAN card is Intel® 82579, 1 x Gigabit LAN Controller(s). This is an in-built card, i.e. it is NOT external. It is not detachable and I cannot remove it from my PC.

My [motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z68V_PROGEN3/specifications/) has these expansion slots:

1. 2 x PCIe 3.0/2.0 x16 (x16 or dual x8)
2. 1 x PCIe 2.0 x16 (x4 mode, 
   black)
3. 2 x PCIe x1
4. 2 x PCI

What is a good model for under 40 dollars?

---

The reason I want to buy another LAN card is because my current card gives me **problems, for example**:

**1.** I have invited my provider's personnel to check my PC, and they said
    I should replace my Internet card because it was damaged in a
    thunderstorm. Now it works worse, and I need to change it.

**2.** Also, my ping grew from 31 to 81, and this is critical for my FPS
    shooter. Also, there is high ping when I have video-conferences, and
    the other person interrupts me.

[image: The card is in the screenshot below]

Comment: HI, I noticed your profile states that you are located in Luhansk Oblast, Ukraine. Does this product need to ship there. For example, [here is a PCIe Ethernet card that costs < $4](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAB1Z5CX2380&ignorebbr=1), but I don't think it can ship to Ukraine.

Comment: Also you could just purchase a USB to Ethernet adapter and this would probably be an easier solution. [Here's one from a popular local purveyor in Ukraine for 413 UAH.](https://rozetka.com.ua/stlab_u_980/p11031997/) I'm not super familiar with Ukraine purveyors so this may not be the best deal possible.

Comment: @Bennett Yeo 
Do you mean all Ethernet cards give the same ping? Now my ping is 81, but it used to be 31 before the card broke. I am going to invite my friend to test my ping on his laptop, to see if his card alo gives this bad ping. First, we will test ping on my machine, and then we will connect his laptop to the same cable, and compare.
But, I have invited support technicians from my provider's, and they

Comment: said my network card was broken, so it might have caused this terrible ping.
So, if the test shows my card needs to be replaced, I'll buy a new one. 
The question is - will they all give the same ping, or maybe some of them produce better ping? Those cards which you described, they are so cheap. Will they produce good ping? Is there any list of Network cards sorted by ping?
PING is the main problem!

Comment: The cards are cheap b/c people don't typically buy Ethernet NIC's like that. Also they have bandwidth up to 1 gigabit, so I don't expect packet latency loss unless you're sending/reciving inordinate amounts of data. In all honesty a ping of less than 100 ms is pretty typical. It's also worth noting that ping is also a function of the performance of the server you are connecting to (video conferencing). In fact if I ping google right now I get a ping delay between 45-75ms.

Comment: @ Bennett Yeo
I cannot leave this problem unsolved, because my work and hobby depend on it. My friend is coming on Saturday with his laptop, and if his ping is better, I will change my Ethernet card. 
When I ping Google, I get 46. 
When I play, the ping is not lower than 81, which makes me ineffective. 
My idea is to have the lowest possible ping on the Ethernet card, and get at least 60, and if possible - get back my 31 (in game).

Comment: @Bennett Yeo Do you think there is any PING difference between the cards which:
1) connect via USB; 2) connect via PCI-PCIe?   10Ms or 5ms? P.S. I am asking because you recommended me USB cards. Maybe, you can recommend me some dummy-friendly article, please?

Comment: The PCIe will be nominally faster, unless your USB interface is directly connected to a PCIe interface. I don't know if your ping will increase as I think the 81 ping might just be the game server. Do you have a way of testing for ping for that server?

Comment: @Bennett Yeo Yeah, the game developers published some tools and guides on their site. However, they look more complicated than asking my friend to bring his laptop. https://forum.star-conflict.com/index.php?/topic/25324-info-connection-losses-high-ping-and-related-issues/

Comment: @Bennett Yeo 
Actually, I have tested my Internet, and the ping is 1 with my provider. The game gives 81, and not better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81622/discussion-between-bennett-yeo-and-sergey-larin).

Comment: I ended up installing fiber Internet with about minus 1 millisecond. 1 or 2 milliseconds.